# Canvas cross-domain image data policy not working with my CMS (Cargo). Do I need a new host?

Tags: javascript, security, canvas, content-management-system, cross-domain

I have a portfolio on Cargo Collective .
I've been trying to implement a JS-driven dynamic header that uses canvas.
[EXAMPLE HERE](http://bit.ly/flakesix-logo)

I am drawing a PNG image on the canvas and capturing pixel information with getImageData().
Everything works fine when I test it locally, but once on Cargo I get the dreaded tainted canvas error:

```
Unable to get image data from canvas because the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data. 
Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18
```

This stems from the fact that on the Cargo CMS images are hosted on their own servers on addresses such as: media.cargocollective.com/1/7/245266/headerimg/FlakeSixBlack.png

The only obvious solution I see to this is to **buy some web space just to host this single image** that I use programmatically. This sounds a bit stupid and partially defeats the purpose of relying on a third-party CMS.

**Is there any other way to work around this?**

**If there isn't, how would I go about managing the DNS A records for two differents hosts?**

My home page address http://flakesix.com would have to point to the Cargo Collective servers, while the image would have to be retrieved from another server (GoDaddy for example, which is where I got the domain name from).

I'm a little lost.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already know what your image is, why not try and embed a base 64 conversion of it within your script ?

Here is some documentation/tool coming to Data Urls :
http://dataurl.net/#about

Comment: Excellent!  I used this [base64 encoder](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp) added a function that returns the encoded PNG called getBase64logo() and changed my bitmap instantiation from this   `var logo = new createjs.Bitmap("img/Logo.png")`   to this   `var logo = new createjs.Bitmap("data:image/png;base64,"+getBase64logo());
`   It works without any cross-domain security issues. Very appropriate especially for small images.

Comment: Happy I helped, yes it has been thought for small images as there are two main drawbacks to base64 encoding :
• size is bigger (from 10% to 30% bigger)
• it is not cacheable as images are